# How to select parts of an ajax response and put them into existing html elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a page where on the first instance, the page displays dynamic content from the DB only once without any Ajax. If the user clicks on a link, I would like to run an Ajax request, Retrieve the title, Date of the entry and the content form the database and replace the existing content in different parts of the page. I'd like to do this without repeating the whole page inside the PHP while loop since Jquery event handlers have been used on the content which is not being refreshed.

My idea was to use a javascript variable with a value of 0 on document load  send it by Ajax and check its value in PHP. If the value is 0 I will set the value of the title, the Date and the content using the latest update in the DB, else I will set it according to the contents of the link.
I am wondering if Ajax can simplify my work.

My Javascript code

```
var statusOfClick =0;
var url = "post_this.php"; 
$.ajax({  //initial request once the document loads 
    url: url,    
    type: "POST",
    data: "statusOfClick="+statusOfClick,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});     

//change the source once the link is clicked    
$("#blog-list ").on("click", "li", function(){
    var getBlogByName = $(this).text();
    var url = "post_this.php";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: "getBlogByName="+getBlogByName,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(){
            /*how do I show parts of this response in different existing 
            html elements?*/
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//change the source once the link is clicked    
    $("#blog-list ").on("click", "li", function(){clicked
    var getBlogByName = $(this).text();
    var url = "post_this.php";
     $.ajax({
     url: url,
     type: "POST",
     data: "getBlogByName="+getBlogByName,
     success: function(response){
     var d = $.parseJSON(response);
     $("#title").html(d.title);
     $("#date").val(d.date);
     $("#content").html(d.content);
      }

     });
```

You can use this code. Encode the response in your PHP file using `json_encode` function. In your JS you can retrieve this values by parsing them into JSON using `$.parseJSON` function. Set the value of date, title and content in respective HTML elements. This is just an example please change it according to your requirement.

Comment: Welcome @FhNdiritu Please mark the answer approved it it has solved your primary issue. Thanks. :)

Comment: While working with your answer I am running into this error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 24
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>) .                                   How do I handle this?

Comment: The problem appears to be inside the JSON feedback, if I try alerting the whole result it works but parsing it does not work.

Comment: Please remove cache, processData and dataType from your code, you don't need that. Sorry i made a mistake in my code.You need to use d to get the values. See my updated answer. @FhNdiritu

Comment: I have made the changes but the issue is still unresolved. My PHP code is running alright, how does JSON handle escape characters? Seems like it might be the issue.